# Closing > in new line

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I have problem with '>' in tags. I got:

```
<label
    class="custom-control-label"
    for="building{{building.Id}}"
>
 {{ building.City }}, {{ building.Name }}
</label>
```

How to make label starting tag '>' in the same line as last attribute? I use Prettier, but I neither couldn't find solution in their config nor in code settings.

```
<label
   class="custom-control-label"
   for="building{{building.Id}}">
     {{ building.City }}, {{ building.Name }}
</label>
```

Solution:
I've used built-in VS Code formatter.

Answer (score 42):

In prettier config use both options, both are important to make it work:

```
"htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore",
"bracketSameLine": true
```

Comment: This is the **correct answer** in 2023

Comment: **#GOTCHA:** Without htmlWhitespaceSensitivity set to "ignore", bracketSameLine doesn't work as expected.

Comment: This worked! Does adding```htmlWhitespaceSensitivity ``` have any side effects?

Answer (score 40):

In **Prettier < 2.4.0**:

- Add `jsxBracketSameLine: true`  in your Prettier settings.

In **Prettier >= 2.4.**, `jsxBracketSameLine` is deprecated, so:

- Add `bracketSameLine: true` in your Prettier settings.

You can refer to the [official documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#bracket-line) for more information.

Comment: so I have the same issue, and this doesn't work. This only work for opening tags, but not for closing tags.

Answer (score 7):

That setting in prettier is called `jsxBracketSameLine` and needs to be set to true

## Documentation

https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#jsx-brackets

Comment: How are you setting your configuration? Are other rules working in the same configuration?

Comment: Yes, I also have: Jsx Single Quote as true and it is working. I use VS Code so in settings I tick proper option. :)

Comment: Have you looked at this documentation on setting configs? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode.

Comment: Yes, I made even file .prettierrc with "jsxBracketSameLine": true and it's not working. I got this file in folder .vscode

Comment: does it work if you run the CLI command? `prettier --jsx-bracket-same-line fileName`

Comment: everything is working but not jsx property - when I disable prettier, everything works good and VSC style my document in good way, I think it may be bug

Comment: I'm looking a solution as well. I believe this rule applies to the entire tag/bracket block `<tag>content</tag>`, not specifically the `>` and how it should be formatted

Answer (score 6):

You can follow [this](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5377) thread.

This a feature request for Prettier.

Answer (score 2):

Go to VSCode Settings and search prettier as shown in the screenshot.
Bracket Same Line

Click on this checkbox

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the prettier property: `bracketSameLine` only works for opening tags `<`, but not for closing tags `>` which does not answer the original question (See this [feature request for reference](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/11484)). For me, I had to change the default formatter from prettier to the VS code default.

I used the command `Format Document With:` and the last option is to change the default formatter which only affects html files (or current type of file being changed). I then selected `HTML Language Features` from the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

In my situtation, With using Angular
I updated prettier from ^1.19.1 to ^2.1.2

`npm i prettier@2.1.2 -D`

Without any property touch, Closing html tag  on the same line.